# Unable to plot Cloudwatch custom metrics on Cloudwatch Graphs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have put some custom metrics in AWS cloudwatch using CLI.

`aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name queuelength --namespace testservice --value 10000 --unit Count --timestamp 2022-11-06T12:05:00.000Z --region us-east-1`

`aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name queuelength --namespace testservice --value 20000 --unit Count --timestamp 2022-11-05T12:05:00.000Z --region us-east-1`

I am getting this namespace and metric name on AWS console after pushing the metrics but when I select it for plotting graph it doesn't show any line.

This is the query that was formed from query builder.
`SELECT SUM(queuelength) FROM SCHEMA(testservice)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timestamps are 3 days in the past. It can take some time for backfilled data to show up.
Try publishing a datapoint more recent to the current time, within the last 3 hours. If that works and you see your data, then the backfilled data should show up within an hour or so.